# Is it possible to run a stored procedure in Oracle for loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a question about a possibility. I have created a stored procedure in Oracle database version 12c. It takes one parameter in order to run. So that it runs correctly by passing the parameter as following:

```
EXEC My_Procedure_Name(parameter_value);
```

And everything goes well by running above code.

Now, I am going to run this procedure (in fact the above code) for two months on a daily basis. Therefore, I have wrote a script like this:

```
declare stmt varchar2(100);
 begin
   for i in (days of months)
  loop
    stmt:='EXEC My_Procedure_Name(parameter_value);';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt; 
    commit;
  end loop;
 end;
```

My question would be: is the mentioned script correct? And will it work? Is there any problem with my script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than this you may try below code without using execute immediate but just referring the loop variable -

```
declare stmt varchar2(100);
 begin
   for i in (days of months)
  loop
    My_Procedure_Name(i.parameter_value);
    commit;
  end loop;
 end;
```

Answer (score 3):

To call a procedure in a loop, the syntax is like this:

```
begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
    end loop;
end;
```

I'm assuming that `for i in (days of months)` is pseudocode and you will actually use some valid construction to meet your requirement.

If you really need to use dynamic code, that can be done, but note that PL/SQL has no `EXEC` keyword. You would need something like:

```
begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        execute immediate 'begin dbms_output.put_line(:i); end;' using i;
    end loop;
end;
```

or

```
begin
    for i in 1..5 loop
        execute immediate 'call dbms_output.put_line(:i)' using i;
    end loop;
end;
```

(Notice that PL/SQL has a `;` statement terminator, but SQL does not.)

As you can see, dynamic code is more complicated so it is best to avoid it unless there is no other option.

Comment: That is considered a great solution. Thanks William